# Error Code: 0 ExceptionMessage: Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error in Angular 5

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, angular5

I am getting this error "Error Code: 0 ExceptionMessage: Http failure response for (unknown URL): 0 Unknown Error" on my Angular 5 project.

However, I am not able to recreate this issue, I saw this repeated issue on the Rollbar error log. I tried the same steps on my local machine, also tried to recreate in different browsers like chrome, safari, etc but no luck.

I'm using AWS lambda with .NET core 2.1, API proxy gateway, and Angular 5 on FrontEnd.

AngularJs code

```
getOrgPublicAssetName(id: number): Observable<any> {
    let content = this.appSharedService.getSitecontents();
    if (content !== '')
      return Observable.of(content);
    if (id !== undefined)
      return <Observable<any>>(
        this.httpClient
          .get(this.organizationUrl + '/SiteContent/' + id)
          .map(result => {
            this.appSharedService.setsitecontents(result);
            return result;
          })
          .pipe(catchError(this.exceptionService.catchBadResponse))
      );
    else return Observable.of();
  }
```

Following is my startup.cs configure function where I am already using cors.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseXRay("Organizations");
            app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));

            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(EnvironmentVariableAWSRegion.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_REGION, Configuration["AWS:Region"]);

            // Create a logging provider based on the configuration information passed through the appsettings.json
            // You can even provide your custom formatting.
            loggerFactory.AddLambdaLogger(Configuration.GetLambdaLoggerOptions());

            //Enable swagger endpoint if the environment is not production

            if (!IsProductionEnvironment)
            {
                // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
                app.UseSwagger();

                // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    if (env.EnvironmentName == "Local")
                        c.SwaggerEndpoint(SwaggerLocalEndpoint, ApiName);
                    else
                        c.SwaggerEndpoint(SwaggerEndpoint, ApiName);
                });
            }

            app.UseCors(policy =>
            {
                //TODO: This has to be addressed once we deploy both api and ui under the same domain
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
                policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                policy.WithExposedHeaders("WWW-Authenticate");
                policy.WithExposedHeaders("X-Total-Count");
            });
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
            {
                routeBuilder.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
                routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", OrganizationModelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
            });
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
            app.UseResponseCaching();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the Angular code when the request is made? If it is a frontend error you should check the URL is OK before making the request (debugging with the browser, for example).

Comment: @adrisons have added the Angular code, please check

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is not allowing your code to read the HTTP response because of the CORS error.

You will see the error in browser console logs (Chrome shows it)

1. Check AWS ApiGateway if OPTIONS request is correctly handled
2. In the Network TAB (if you are using Chrome), check the pre-flight request
3. You must check `access-control-allow-origin` header param sent by
   server in the network logs (response headers) and ensure it is
   correctly configured

If nothing works, delete the API gateway configuration and recreate them (it would be easy if you have cloud formation scripts). It always works

[image: Response headers]

Comment: This issue happens only for few users and, if I test this now it works. Since it's not reproducible so it's very difficult to test the same. I have also checked all the things you mentioned in the comment but still no luck.

Comment: In that case, check if access-control-origin is correctly returned when HTTP_STATUS is not 200. In other words, check it when an error occurs. By default AWS gateway do not send CORS headers when error occurs. Add CORS to 4xx and 5xx or whatever the code is returned back

Comment: It may be that few users getting this problem are not getting CORS correctly

Comment: Yeah, but unable to understand why only a few users facing the CORS issue and others are not even though they use the same functionality and same URL. I confirm this is not related to browser too, so definitely its a CORS issue but looks very weird.